# git difference does not work properly after git clone

Tags: bash, git

I have a bash script in which I have to clone and get difference of some repositories.
I am trying to get difference between range of a date

```
git clone $repository 
cd $path
git diff master@{2019-10-1}..master@{2019-10-14} -- package.json
```

but it shows error:
**warning: Log for 'master' only goes back to Tue, 15 Oct 2019 09:51:16 +0000.**

But this repository is old and has many commits.
when I do it locally on the machine in which I had cloned same repository some weeks back I get proper difference.

```
$ git diff master@{2019-10-1}..master@{2019-10-14} -- package.json
diff --git a/package.json b/package.json
index d29ffcb..8766fde 100644
--- a/package.json
+++ b/package.json
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 {
   "name": "accountd",
-  "version": "0.0.95",
+  "version": "0.0.102",
   "main": "dist/src/index.js",
   "private": true,
   "scripts": {
@@ -8,7 +8,8 @@
     "start-dev": "npm run build && nodemon . port=5000 stage",
     "start-sand": "npm run build && nodemon . port=5000 stage",
-    "test": "nyc --extension .ts --reporter=html --reporter=cobertura --reporter=text mocha -r ts-node/register src/**/*.spec.ts --exit",
+    "test": "mocha -r ts-node/register test/**/*.spec.ts  test/**/**/*.spec.ts --exit",
```

I want the changes made in this specific file over a period of time.

Comment: What does "git log" show?

Comment: git log works well.
```
$ git log
commit 509304552b99745d5666cdcdmkmk97ba96eaf12897aa (HEAD -> master, tag: 0.0.63, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Author: Unnati Desai <Udesai@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Oct 15 04:45:23 2019 +0000

    chore(release): Publish 0.0.63 from CI System. [ci skip]

commit 1cb8e366bb3738db85c2d048bc85c54794e579b9
Merge: a2eb2c2 351a17d
Author: vedati Pathk <pveda@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Oct 14 23:33:30 2019 -0500

    Merge pull request #123 from yui/customer-ideal-changes

    customer-ideal-changes

    - No win in the change view ( #102 )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notation you're using (`master@{<date>}`) says that you want to refer to the version of `master` on `<date>` *according to the local reflogs*.  That is, you're saying that you want to know what this particular clone's `master` ref pointed to on that date - not what of the current `master` commits had been committed on that date.

And git is telling you "this clone didn't have a `master` ref on that date".

To do what you mean, you first have to find the last commit before the "then' date, then `diff` against that.  There are a number of ways, but something like

```
git diff $(git rev-list -n1 --before="<date>" --first-parent master) master
```

might be more what you want

Comment: so should I do 
```git rev-list -n1 --before="startdate" --first-parent master``` here I will get last commit and then again I have get ```git rev-list -n1 --before="enddate" --first-parent master``` here I will get another commit. Then I have to do ```git diff <commit from 1st command> <commit from 2nd command>```

Comment: @Mansi - If you have both a start date and an end date (I guess I misread that the first time), then yes, you would use that approach to get the two commits.  As noted in the answer, you can combine these into one commit using the `$()` notation if you're running a bash-like shell

Comment: I did this way `git diff $(git rev-list -1 --before=$startDate "master")...$(git rev-list -1 --before=$endDate "master") -- pom.xml`

Answer (score 0):

The `@{date}` syntax will not get you what you want.  I'd go into what you *do* want, but I got beaten to the answer; see [Mark Adelsberger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58398554/1256452) instead. :-)

#### What to know about the `@{...}` syntax

With the `@{date}` syntax, it doesn't matter how old the *repository source* is.  It does not matter how many *commits* you have.  All that matters is what is in this particular clone's so-called *reflogs*.

Every Git repository—every clone—has its own reflogs.  In general, no two different Git repositories will agree as to what goes into the reflogs.  The reflogs are not meant for this kind of job.  Which kind of job?  *This* kind:

> I want the changes made in this specific file over a period of time.

The reflogs tell you absolutely nothing about changes in files, or changes not in files, over time.  They tell you about changes in your Git's *references* over time.

This may leave you puzzling over what, precisely, a *ref* or *reference* is.  We probably should not go into too much detail here, but every branch name like `master` is actually a reference whose full spelling is `refs/heads/master`; every tag name like `v1.2` is a ref whose full spelling is `refs/tags/v1.2`; and every remote-tracking name like `origin/master` is a ref whose full spelling starts with `refs/remotes/`.  So they're just a generalization of the various names that humans tend to use, to talk about commits.  What *Git* needs, to talk about commits, is their raw hash IDs.  The *names* are, to some extent, just there so that us weak humans don't have to remember arbitrary, big ugly hash IDs.<sup>1</sup>

The key to understanding this, and the `@{...}` syntax, is to realize that these names—e.g., `refs/heads/master`—*change* over time.  Right now, your `master` commit might be `a123456...`.  Yesterday, it might have been some other commit, and tomorrow, it might be yet another commit.  *Your* Git's `master` will change over time, and every time it does change, *your* Git keeps a record of what it *was*.  This record only goes back so far: the *commits* are permanent, but the record of which hash ID `master` meant, when, is not.  Moreover, it's not carried from one clone to another: *Every* clone's record of what `master` meant when is *private to that one particular Git*.  In a fresh clone—which has *all* the commits<sup>2</sup>—there's only one value `master` has ever had, which is what it has right now.

Note that you can also use `@{number}`.  This selects the number'th entry in the reflog.

To view the actual reflog for any particular ref, run `git reflog ref`, e.g., `git reflog master`.  The `git reflog` command has various other sub-commands for dealing with the logs, too.  See [its documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) for details.

---

<sup>1</sup>The names do have other functions.  For much more about this, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).

<sup>2</sup>Assuming it's not a *shallow* clone, that is, and not using some of the new "promisor pack" features that are not yet in general use.  Also, if you cloned with `-b` or `--single-branch`, or the upstream repository is set up in a less-usual fashion, you might not have a branch named `master` yet at all.